# SQL query to retrieve last twelve months data for Oracle database

Tags: sql, oracle

I am using Oracle database. I have a table called "`TEST`" where the dates/timestamps(These are stored as "Char" in my case) are stored in the following format. Now I want to retrieve the records of last twelve months based on today's date. What would be the correct way to do that?

```
TESTCOLUMN
------------
2019-06-28-02.01.07.327240
2020-06-28-04.49.12.480240
2020-06-28-05.05.10.681240
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to use the `ADD_MONTHS` function and `BETWEEN` clause as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE TO_TIMESTAMP(YOUR_COLUMN,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS.FF') 
      BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSTIMESTAMP,-12) AND SYSTIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. +1 for your quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Although storing values in a string is not recommended, your format is comparable.  So you can do the comparison using strings rather than date/timestamps.  Assuming your values are only in the past:

```
where testcolumn >= to_char(SYSTIMESTAMP, -12), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24.MI.SS.FF')
```

This has an advantage over Tejash's solution, because this can make use of an index (or partitions) on `testcolumn`.  Moving the date manipulations only on the "constants" (i.e. the system timestamp) helps the Oracle optimizer.